# Dynamically update FormBuilder group inputs

Tags: javascript, html, angular, formbuilder

```
When FormGroup instance is created it creates a FormGroup object that has controls and values.
I have one form that has different controls, they activate depending on what type of form was chosen.
The problem is that formGroup instance stays same, so my controls are not read, and I am getting an error that controls are not found.
```

I will include task.component.ts file where i update a task and read values into input fields:

```
upateTaskForm(taskBody, taskType) {
    this.formActive = true;
    if (this.task === 'medication') {
      console.log(this.formGroup + "MEDICATION FORMGROUP");
      this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        title: taskBody.title,
        instructions: taskBody.instructions,
        repeatWeekDay: [null],
        medication: this.formBuilder.group({
          name: taskBody.medication[0].name,
          dose: this.formBuilder.group({
            quantity: taskBody.medication[0].quantity,
            unit: taskBody.medication[0].dose.unit
          }),
          method: taskBody.medication[0].method,
          notes: taskBody.medication[0].notes
        })
      });
      // Reading Form populates from the formbuilder
    } if (this.task === 'reading') {
      console.log(this.formGroup + "READING FORMGROUP");
      this.formBuilder.group({
        title: taskBody.title,
        reading: this.formBuilder.group({
          measureType: taskBody.reading[0].measureType,
          measureValue: taskBody.reading[0].measureValue,
          measureUnits: taskBody.reading[0].measureUnits,
        }),
        instructions: taskBody.instructions,
      });
    } else if (this.task === 'symptoms') {
      this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        title: [null, Validators.required],
        instructions: [null]
      });
    }
  }
```

This is HTML code for the task.component.html
formGroup is an instance of the form and, once its submited values are stored in formGroup.value
formGroup is
        
              
                
                  Copy from library
                  
                    Search Tasks in Library
                    
                  
                
                
                  Name
                  
                
                
                  Event
                  
                    
                       Medication

```
                <label class="form-check-label d-block d-md-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" (click)="setTask('reading')" name="event" [checked]='task==="reading"' value="measurement"> Measurement</label>

                <label class="form-check-label d-block d-md-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" (click)="setTask('record-symptoms')" name="event" [checked]='task==="symptoms"'
                    value="symptoms"> Record Syptoms</label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Medication Form -->
            <div id="medicationForm" formArrayName="medication" *ngIf="task==='medication'">
              <div class="form-group row mx-auto mt-4" formArrayName="dose">

                <label class="col-md-3" for="response">Dose</label>
                <input type="number" name="number" class="form-contol col-md-6 mr-4" placeholder="Quantity" formControlName="quantity">
                <select class="col" formControlName="unit">
                  <option default>Tablet(s)</option>
                  <option>Pill</option>
                  <option>Liquid</option>
                </select>

              </div>

              <div class="form-group row mx-auto mt-4">
                <label class="col-md-3"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-contol col-md-6 mr-4" placeholder="Unit / eg Melformin 500mg" formControlName="name">
                <select class="col" formControlName="method">
                  <option default>Oral</option>
                  <option>IV</option>
                  <option>Tropical</option>
                  <option>ophthalmic</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row mx-auto mt-4">
                <label for="notes" class="col">Notes</label>
                <input type="text" name="notes" class="form-control col-md-9 ml-auto" placeholder="Take before bed, take before eating" formControlName="notes">
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Measurement Form -->
            <div id="measurementForm" *ngIf="task==='reading'" formArrayName="reading" >
              <div class="form-group row mx-auto mt-4">
                <label class="col-md-3">Measurement Type</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-contol col" placeholder="Heart_rate, Systolic, Diastolic, Weight" formControlName="measureType">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row mx-auto mt-4">
                <label class="col-md-3" for="response">Measurement Value</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-contol col-md-6 mr-4" placeholder="Value of the measurement" formControlName="measureValue">
                <select class="col" formControlName="measureUnits">
                  <option default>KG</option>
                  <option>LBS</option>
                  <option>mmHg</option>
                  <option>MG/DL</option>
                  <option>MMOL</option>
                  <option>STEPS</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row mx-auto">
              <label class="col" for="instructions">Instructions</label>
              <input class="form-control col-md-9 ml-auto" type="text" formControlName="instructions" placeholder="Anything to say to the patient">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer my-3">
              <button class="d-none d-md-block btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-md-lg mr-auto ml-md-4" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
              <button class="d-md-none btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-md-lg mr-auto ml-md-4" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <button type="submit" class="d-none d-md-block btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-md-lg mr-md-4">CREATE TASK</button>
              <button class="d-md-none btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-md-lg mr-md-4">OK</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Jku.jpg)

Comment: In task.ts, are you trying to clear the form ?

Comment: you are telling about dynamic field adding and removing? is it?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the FormBuilder class once, to get an instance of FormGroup. After that, if you need to dynamically add or remove FormControls, you can use the addControl and removeControl methods.

Comment: What if I want to create a new instance of FormGroup?I don't want to repeat code 2 or 3 times, in order to add controls